# What do you think about returning the logging sentence

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have this java code:

```
if(isNull(office) || isNull(pricelist)) {
    log.warn("The document {0}-{1} is not valid.",codDoc,numDoc);
    return null;
}
```

Do you think it is ok if I rewrite it as:

```
if(isNull(office) || isNull(pricelist)) 
    return log.warn("The document {0}-{1} is not valid.",codDoc,numDoc);
```

That way

```
public void warn(String logLine, Object... args)
{...}
```

would become:

```
public Object warn(String logLine, Object... args)
{...;return null;}
```

Take into consideration that logging is mandatory in this system.
Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It's not clear to me.

Comment: I was trying to reduce the number of lines of code, but, as everyone points out, it is not a good idea at all, it sacrifices clarity and introduces a weird API, thank you very much for your quick answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would never do that as it creates a surprising API. In Java especially, the point is not tersness, the point is clarity. Having an extra line for the return is valuable in that it tells you the return isn't related to the logging.

And if you are in a method that itself has a void return you would have to put the return on a seperate line anyway.

And anyway, if you declare it to return Object, the method has to return Object, or else you have to cast it down, which gets even worse. You could work on that with generics:

```
  public <T> T warn(String message, Object... params) { return null; }
```

But none of this seems to be a good idea in the general case.

Answer (score 2):

If you're always going to return null from the `warn` method, then it wouldn't make any difference either way; no additional functionality is enabled and no additional information is provided.  I would only perform the change if some external entity demands that your logging method match a signature where `Object` is returned.

Comment: I second that. Plus, Java programmers worldwide are used to "log.warn" being used for its side effect ONLY, with nothing returned. Anyone new reading your code will be confused to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you need the logging to do.

If your system needs to have an object be created like an exception during the logging process, the second way (Object warn()) might work for you.

It really depends on what you need....

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it's OK to rewrite it as you've suggested.

Couple of reasons.

1. Many standard log APIs have `void`
   return type for `warn` method.  For
   somebody familiar with these APIs it
   would be a *surprizing* side-effect
2. Your `warn` method does not return a
   real object, it always returns
   `null`.  This would be *surprizing*
   for maintainer to find this out.

Answer (score 0):

Use the first method.

The reason being that the second method implies that the return value from the warn method is meaningful.  The second method, as written, forces the return value from the warn method to appear as if it were the return value from the caller of the warn method and this is probably the wrong thing to return, especially if the design has various return values to handle various warning conditions.